# Create or new in Rails controller in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, we define the `create` action 2 ways. What are the difference?

```
def create
  @shop = Shop.new(params[:shop])
  if @shop.save
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for adding new shop.'
    redirect_to @shop
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Error adding review,  please try again.'
    redirect_to @shop
  end
end

# or

def create
  @shop = Shop.create(params[:shop])
  if @shop.save
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for adding new shop.'
    redirect_to @shop
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Error adding review,  please try again.'
    redirect_to @shop
  end
end
```

Considering we already have:

```
def new
  @shop = Shop.new
end
```

Which is more proper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `Model.create`, you don't need to save the object explicitly. The create method will do that for you.
If you used `Model.new`, you need to save the object by doing @object.save. The new 
method does not do that for you.

**Using Model.new:**

```
def create
  @shop = Shop.new(params[:shop])
   if @shop.save
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for adding new shop.'
    redirect_to @shop
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Error adding review,  please try again.'
    redirect_to @shop
  end
end
```

**Using Model.create:**

```
def create
  @shop = Shop.create(params[:shop])
   # if @shop.save (This is not required)
  if @shop 
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for adding new shop.'
    redirect_to @shop
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Error adding review,  please try again.'
    redirect_to @shop
  end
end
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yeah, I tried using just `@shop` and it fails silently, didn't output any validation message.

Comment: Yeah, the `User.create!` method works just like the create method...except that it raises an `ActiveRecord::Record-Invalid exception` if the creation fails.

Comment: So to save troubles, I guess the combination of `Model.new` and `if @model.save` is a good one huh?

Comment: yes and that way you can also pass the flash message after successful save..pretty good. :)

Answer (score 3):

This `def new` action is just for the `New` view (the `new` action in your `Shop` controller would correspond to the `app/views/shop/new.html.erb` file) - it doesn't do any creation:

```
def new
  @shop = Shop.new
end
```

There is no mention of `params[:shop]` in that action, because the parameters don't exist yet - that's what you're gathering in the `New` view.

Your `def create` action is the action that actually creates the database entry:

```
def create
  @shop = Shop.new(params[:shop])
  if @shop.save
    flash[:success] = 'Thanks for adding new shop.'
    redirect_to @shop
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Error adding review,  please try again.'
    redirect_to @shop
  end
end
```

You're using `.new` instead of `.create` so that you can do validations. Also, the `Shop.new` call doesn't actually create the record - it's `@shop.save` that does that.

Answer (score 2):

The first way doesn't do what you expect:

```
def create
  @shop = Shop.new(params[:shop]) # This won't create a new record on Shops table unless...
  @show.save                      # ...you do this
end

def create
  @shop = Shop.create(params[:shop]) # This will create a new record if everything is fine
  if @shop.save # This is redundant
    # ...
  end
end
```

Calling `create` and then `save` is redundant. The `create` method will try to make a new record and fail silently if validations are not successful. In the other hand, `save` will try to make a new record, but returns `nil` if vaildations fail, so you can use it in a *if/else* block.

Comment: I added validation question to consider the move. Could you update your answer?

Comment: So one should use `new` then `save` in `if-else` if he doesn't want `create` to fail silently?

Comment: Basically, yes. However, neither of these methods raise error, so they wont interrupt the flow of your app. `save` returns `nil` on failure which is useful for conditional blocks.

Answer (score 1):

In `create` controller action, `Shop.new` is useless without following `@shop.save`. Usually it's being split into these two steps to handle validation errors. We init shop with data from the user. If data is ok, we save the shop. If there are validation errors, we tell user to try again.

Or we need to do some complex attribute initialisation before we save record to the database.

```
@user = User.new params[:user]
@user.reputation = fetch_reputation_from_stackoverflow

if @user.save
  # the usual steps here
```

### RE: question edit

> Considering we already have:

```
def new
  @shop = Shop.new
end
```

What is there in `new` action is completely irrelevant. If your validations might fail (or otherwise your model might not be created successfully), then use `new` + `save` pair. If you are sure that input data is ok and model will always save, then use only `create` (following `save` is redundant).

Comment: I added validation question to consider the move. Could you update your answer?